# Change color of specific part of element string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, element, createelement

I'm creating a chat application, and I want the users text's to be colored. Here is how I create the text element:

```js
var item = document.createElement('li'); 
item.textContent = `[Anye]: hello`;
item.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
item.style.color = 'red';
```

This is how this code is executed:

[image: Current]

This, on the other hand, is what I would want:

[image: Desired]

Is there a way that I can change the color of only *part* of the text?

**Note: The desired image was created using the console, and please keep in mind that the messages are not fixed, it's up to the user what they want to say.**

I'm willing to use `jQuery` for this example, if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the author in a `span` element and set style property.

```js
var item = document.createElement('li'); 
item.style.fontWeight = 'bold';

const author = document.createElement("span");
author.innerText = "[Anye]: ";
author.style.color = 'red';

item.append(author);
item.innerHTML += "hello";

document.body.append(item);
```

Or you can wrap the message in a `span` element and set a predefined style in CSS.

```js
var item = document.createElement('li'); 
item.innerHTML = `[Anye]: <span>hello</span>`;
item.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
item.style.color = 'red';

document.body.append(item);
```

```css
li span {
  color: initial;
}
```